# Segmented control addTarget() crashing app below iOS 9.0

Tags: swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol, addtarget

My app has been released recently but it supports iOS 8.2.

Unfortunately, below iOS 9.0 tapping a segmented control which has been added programmatically crashes the app with no error message in the console.

I believe that the line where the target is added may cause the issue:

The following line is placed inside the init() of my custom cell, the segmented control is an instance var and calls a method in its parent view controller

```
segmentedControl.addTarget(ListViewController(), action: #selector(ListViewController.segmentedControlToggled(segmentedControl:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

Again, this works as expected down to iOS 9.0.

The setup works fine, it only crashes once the segmented control is tapped.

Should there be another syntax for the selector?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation of [addTarget](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget):

> The control does not retain the object in the target parameter. It is your responsibility to maintain a strong reference to the target object while it is attached to a control.

Which means that you need to store the value of the `target` parameter somewhere, thing you fail to achieve:

```
segmentedControl.addTarget(ListViewController(),...)
```

The `ListViewController` will get deallocated as soon as there will be no other references to it, the important thing to remember here is that you can't know in advance when the deallocation will happen, as you don't know how may other objects will refer your object.

To make sure the target doesn't get deallocated, store the `ListViewController` instance into a property.

The crash is not particular to the iOS version, it might be that on some iOS version the `ListViewController` gets deallocated sooner.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Cristik, I have overlooked that. I changed it and it fixed the issue! However, I'm still puzzled as to why this works in every version above 8.4, but not below.

Comment: @nontomatic It could be that the target gets caught (retained) by other objects which indirectly keep it alive. And iOS 8.3 and below doesn't have those objects. Basically your app works fine in 8.4 and above due to some implementation details of UIKit, however since those are out of your control, you better keep a strong reference for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, that does make sense, thanks!